# Convert one column csv into Dictionary with same key:value pair in python 2.7 (using import csv)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, python-2.x, read.csv

I have one CSV file as sample.csv which contains 
ABC 
XYZ 
LMN 
...

And from this file, I have to make a dictionary like below

Dict = {'ABC':'ABC','XYZ':'XYZ','LMN':'LMN',...}

using import csv

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import csv

dict = {}
with open("sample.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # I'm assuming you can use all content in a single cell as a key
        key_str = " ".join(row)
        dict[key_str] = key_str
```

The "trick" here is just to set each key "key_str" to be equal to the value (also "key_str"). This can also all be accomplished within a single pass through the csv file.